# C# Updating user to AD throws 'The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid.'

Tags: c#, active-directory

Updating some fields doesn't work while others do. Even though old value and new value are strings exception is thrown.

```
UserPrincipal user = GetUser();
var userEntry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

// When creating user this kind of stuff works
userEntry.Properties["pager"].Add("12345");
user.Save();

// When updating this doesn't work for attributes
// E.g. mobile has value "+12 34 567 89 01" of type String
userEntry.Properties["mobile"].Value = "0345678901"; // not ok
user.Save();
// Exception 'The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid.'

// also not ok
userEntry.Properties["mobile"].RemoveAt(0);
userEntry.Properties["mobile"].Add("0345678901");
user.Save();
```

Comment: have you tried getting the mobile property value and setting it as is? It could be that you are not setting the correct format. Try it out.

Comment: Does userEntry.CommitChanges get a different result?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado userEntry.Properties[propertyName].Value = userEntry.Properties[propertyName].Value; still error

Comment: @theoretical it doesn't make a difference

Comment: @MikaKolari did you try `userEntry.Properties[propertyName].Value = userEntry.Properties[propertyName].Value;` without `userEntry.Properties["mobile"].RemoveAt(0);`?

Comment: Check that the value provided for the attribute  matches its type in active directory schema of your ad

Comment: @MikaKolari Did you try `userEntry.InvokeSet("mobile", "0123456");`?